# FormulaR1C1 Error 1004, how do I solve this issue?

Tags: excel, vba

I get this error for this line of code

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=INDEX(FILTER(Table1[#All],(Table1[[#All],[Placement Type]]=""Top of search (page 1)"")*(Table1[[#All],[Campaign]]='SP KW'!RC[-29])),28)"
```

Previously I was using Office 365 and it was working fine, now I change to Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 and I continue to receive this error.

Comment: The [FILTER function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) does not exist in *Professional Plus 2016*. It was introduced with *Excel for Microsoft 365*. So your formula is just not compatible with the old Excel version.

Comment: Love it! Thanks a lot!